# how to remove the shadow of png in ie6

Tags: css

Written pages, why in the ie6 png images in it will automatically cast a shadow

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons, depending on how it looks.

- IE 6 doesn't support transparency for PNG images (unless you use a filter to display the image), so if there is a transparent background in the image it will be replaced with a solid gray.
- The PNG format contains a gamma correction value that was intended to solve some color profiling problems, but it actually hurts as much as it helps as images are displayed somewhat differently on different systems. If you have a color in your PNG image that is supposed to match the background of the page, it might be slightly off, which will show the iamge as a square with a slightly different color.

Answer (score 0):

that's one of the many bugs of IE6: wrong rendering of transparent png's.

there are a lot of JS fixes, like [this one](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/), but i've never seen one that works perfectly.
some break the clickable elements that have png background, some others change alignment or margis or position